# Height of a div not set correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So if you open this page in chrome http://gameittourney.fyoucon.com you'll see that the height of one something is not set correct, press on home and its now how it's supposed to be
Picture for those without chrome [image]
How its supposed to look [image]
I have no idea why this is happening

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainContent").css("height", window.innerHeight);
    $(".leftContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height());
    $(".rightContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height());

    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;

    if (footerTop < docHeight) {
    $('#footer').css('margin-top', 10 + (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
    }

    var mh = $(window).height();
    var h = $(document).height();
    if( mh < h) {
        $("#mainContent").css("height", h);
        $(".leftContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height());
        $(".rightContentBorder").css("height",   $("#mainContent").height());   
    }


$(window).resize(function() {
    var mh = $(window).height();
    var h = $(document).height();
    if( mh < h) {
        $("#mainContent").css("height", h);
        $(".leftContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height());
        $(".rightContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height()); 
    }
    else {
        $("#mainContent").css("height", window.innerHeight);
        $(".leftContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height());
        $(".rightContentBorder").css("height", $("#mainContent").height());

    }

    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;

    if (footerTop < docHeight) {
    $('#footer').css('margin-top', (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
    }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="resize.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<title>GameIT Tourney</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="contentBox">
    <div class="leftContentBorder"></div>
    <div class="rightContentBorder"></div>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div class="header"><a href="/"><img src="img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/Header_img.png" /></a></div>
        <div class="navBar">
            <ul>
                <a href="/"><li>HOME</li></a>
                <a href="/"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
                <a href="/"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            The GameIT College Tourney is a "web hub" to the different<br/>
 e-Sports tournaments hosted on Campus Djursland.<br/><br/>
            Do you plan on making a tournament? With prizes or just for fun?<br/>
 Contact us at;<br/>
            <a href="mailto:CampusDjurslandTourney@fyoucon.com" class="email">CampusDjurslandTourney@fyoucon.com</a><br/>
            and we'll help you host the information and register participants.
      </div>
        <div class="divideLineBig"></div>
        <div class="currentTour">
            <div class="titel"><img src="img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/Right_arrow.png"/>
            CURRENT TOURNAMENTS
            <img src="img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/Left_arrow.png"/>
            <div class="divideLineSmall"></div>
            </div>
            <a href="/"><img class="imageCenter" src="img/LolT.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="divideLineBig"></div>
        <div class="currentTour" style="background-color:#e1e1e1;">
            <div class="titel"><img src="img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/past_pil_right.png"/>
            PAST TOURNAMENTS
            <img src="img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/RESTEN/past_pil_left.png"/>
            <div class="divideLineSmall"></div>
            </div>
            <a href="/"><img class="imageCenter" src="img/LolT.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        <img class="imageCenter" src="img/CampusDjursland_Tourneyhjemmeside_grafik/FOOTER/Footer_divideline.png"/>
            <div style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                All images are the properties of their respective owners.<br>
                Coded by Mikkel Hjortshoej © 2013 | Graphics and Design by Alexander Nass Kahr © 2013
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looked like that the first time i opened it in Firefox, but ever since i hit 'home' its okay. weird.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can accomplish your styles with pure CSS no need for all the Javascript code

Comment: Well I tried and nothing really worked so I did it with jQuery

Comment: $("#mainContent").css("height", window.innerHeight);

You are setting the height of the div to the window's height, i.e height = part of the screen visible to the user.

Comment: Yes but then i check if the viewport is less than the document and then resize it accordingly, but its not doing it right in chrome for me only in firefox

Comment: Try using $(document).height(); instead of window.innerHeight

Comment: Nope still have the same issue

Comment: Try using $("#mainContent").css("height", 1000px); in the first line

Comment: The error is still there

Answer (score 0):

If I understand yor problem correctly (the surrounding div not expanding to with height of the child content), if you add display:block; to the  inside of the .currentTour class, you should be good.

```
.currentTour a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: .currentTour isnt the problem, on the other pages the same problem appears